# Flutter TextField value always uppercase & debounce

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield, uppercase, debouncing

I am new in Flutter. I am looking for TextField value to always uppercase but I did not find any resource on that.

Another issue is the TextField onChanged event debounce implementation. When I type on TextField it immediately fires **onChanged** event which is not suitable for my goal. The onChange event will fire after 500ms on every text changed.

```
 new TextField(
         controller: _controller,
         decoration: new InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Search here',
         ),
         onChanged: (str) {
            //need to implement debounce
         }
)
```

Comment: Do you want to capitalize the first character or all text? You can use debounce from https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxdart

Comment: Need all character uppercase. @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: Your question covers two different aspects of TextField. Please ask two questions next time. I am declinging to upvote on an otherwise good question.

Answer (score 233):

Works on **Android, iOS, Web, macOS, Windows and Linux**

You can implement a custom [`TextInputFormatter`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/TextInputFormatter-class.html)

```
class UpperCaseTextFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    return TextEditingValue(
      text: newValue.text.toUpperCase(),
      selection: newValue.selection,
    );
  }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
TextField(
  inputFormatters: [
    UpperCaseTextFormatter(),
  ]
)
```

[Full example](https://github.com/flutter/gallery/blob/master/lib/demos/material/text_field_demo.dart#L322)

Comment: I don't know why this solution doesn't have more upvotes. From what I can tell, this is the correct way to implement automatic uppercase formatting (or any kind of text field formatting).

Comment: Hey you don't actually need to implement the textinputformater if you just need in one 
 specific place, take a look at my answer on how to use it without extending TextInputFormatter

Comment: This answer causing an error when enabled AutoCorrect in the Keyboard (it is appending OldValue with NewValue). 

Ex: I wanted to type KEYBOARD: 1st letter type K, 2nd letter type E, now it replaces with KKE and so on letter by letter typing it is appending OldValue with NewValue.

Comment: @rjkolli  I'm unable to reproduce your problem.  This solution seems to work.

Comment: @rjkolli yeah looks like you are right, I am also facing the same issue on some android devices.

Comment: Perfect. `textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,` doesnt work on windows so this a great solution.

Comment: how about capitalize each word ?

Comment: and `textCapitalization` dosent work on other language keyboard @West

Comment: after using this keyboard switching issue is happening.

Comment: This solution is running up against a new Android keyboard issue.  It's appending, not replacing.  Needs an update.

Comment: The question was about "uppercase & debounce". This is a partial answer, that only addresses the uppercase, without a debounce.

Comment: I do this together with textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters - then it works on all platforms and also displays the keyboard with capital letters

Comment: I have the same problem on Android using this solution @rjkolli. I had to go to the `textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters`solution for now and add a toUppercase to the value passed on my onChanged method.

Comment: Caution! This solution is not working correctly with backspace on newer Android devices. It allows removing only one char and then stops! This fixes it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68556182/2734478

Answer (score 113):

Perhaps using textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters in the TextField could help you? Although this would capitalize the characters while something is being typed as well.

```
TextField(
    textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
)
```

Comment: @praveenb does the textCapitalization.sentences does not work completely while typing in textfield or the value fails to be capitalized? p.s. Each sentence's first word only is capitalized and it's activated after each full stop ( . ) .

Comment: yes my mistake... I see if i Enter text in Textfield then its get capitalised. Previously, i prepopulated text for which capitalisation not worked. I thought it should. Thanks for clarification :)

Answer (score 56):

You can use `textCapitalization` property of a `TextField` widget. Also do take a reference for detailed API info here [Text Capitalization Official API](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/TextCapitalization.html)

Illustration as follow

Example 1

```
 TextField(
        initialValue: flutter code camp
        textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,
    )// OUTPUT : FLUTTER CODE CAMP
```

Example 2

```
 TextField(
        initialValue: flutter code camp
        textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
    )// OUTPUT : Flutter Code Camp
```

Example 3

```
 TextField(
        initialValue: flutter code camp
        textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
    )// OUTPUT : Flutter code camp
```

Example 4

```
 TextField(
        initialValue: flutter code camp
        textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.none,
    )// OUTPUT : flutter code camp
```

Answer (score 28):

Everything you need to do is:

After String put **`.toUpperCase()`**

Example: **`"Some text".toUpperCase()`**

This worked in my case. I am new too, so I hope I helped.

Comment: this is about a text input field. there is no string that you could alter. the given text is retrieved via TextEditingController which should be then used to modify the text in the field at every keystroke. I dont think thats possible.

Answer (score 19):

You can use `TextCapitalization.characters` to make all typed characters UPPERCASE

```
TextField(
    textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,
)
```

Comment: Is not ok because its just switches user's keyboard to uppercase but user can switch back to lowercase. Formatter solution is much better

Comment: Also, has no effect on MacOS

Answer (score 12):

@Günter-Zöchbauer's solution works but when you switch into the numeric keyboard on Android, if you type one, it'll switch into the letters keyboard again.

This is because you're setting a new TextEditingValue every time.

Instead, if you copy the newest one and change the text, it works:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class UpperCaseTextFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    return newValue.copyWith(text: newValue.text.toUpperCase());
  }
}
```

Comment: Although this solution still prints a `Composing region changed by the framework. Restarting the input method.` in the console, the issue with numeric keyboards (and also holding backspace) is resolved with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to do it is to add the onChanged event of the TextField and convert to uppercase using the controller of the TextField just like the above:

```
TextField(
          controller: controllerReservation,
          onChanged: (value) {               
            controllerReservation.value = 
               TextEditingValue(
                                text: value.toUpperCase(), 
                                selection: controllerReservation.selection);
          },
        )
```

Comment: this will move the cursor position to start

Comment: @Wahyu I'm pretty sure I've tested when posted this answer and it didn't. But I will test it again and post an improved version if needed.

Comment: @DiegoGarcia, I just used your code example and it, indeed, does set the cursor to the start of the string and reverses the string

Comment: @PaulStoner sorry for the long time to answer, I've edited with the fix !!

Comment: this is imperative thinking. flutter is all about the opposite.

Answer (score 7):

TextField has a textCapitalization property that you can use to capitalize words Sentences or characters

if you want to capitalize the entire value of your text input use

```
TextField(
  textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,
 )
```

Comment: Im not able to post full code in comments but if you have a simple flutter app and throw in a textfield you can easily verify this on flutter desktop

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you achieve Debounce (or delay) effect on input text:

1) Import package

```
rxdart: ^0.18.1 (or whatever the version will be)
```

2) In your Stateful Widget declare following

```
final subject = new PublishSubject<String>();
```

3) In the same Stateful Widget, declare the following under initState method

```
subject.stream
    .debounce(new Duration(milliseconds: 500))
    .listen(_loadNewData);
```

4) In the same Stateful Widget, create the following method (that will be fired after 500 ms)

```
  void _loadNewData(String newData) {
    //do update here
  }
```

4) Add the following line to your Textfield Widget (you can get rid of Controller now)

```
onChanged: (string) => (subject.add(string)),
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your `TextFormField`

```
 inputFormatters: [UpperCaseTextFormatter()],
 textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,
```

**Full code**

```
  TextFormField(
      autofillHints: [AutofillHints.name],
      inputFormatters: [UpperCaseTextFormatter()],
      textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
      horizontal: 0, vertical: 0),
      labelText: "Hello World",
      hintText: '',
    ),
 ),
```

Comment: And where is definition of `UpperCaseTextFormatter`?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this TextInputFormatter constructor is only available in new versions of flutter, but today I found it and it's handy :-D

```
TextField(
  inputFormatters: [
    TextInputFormatter.withFunction((oldValue, newValue) {
                  return newValue.copyWith(text: newValue.text.toUpperCase());
    })
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TextField(
  controller: textController,
    onChanged: (value) {
      if (textController.text != value.toUpperCase())
        textController.value = textController.value.copyWith(text: value.toUpperCase());
  },
)
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Here's simple approach to type in CAPS ON]

```
 textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,
```

Easy!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thanks Apoorv

Comment: doesnot working bro.

Comment: @RahulKushwaha Oops! maybe something got changed can you share the code so I have a look?

Answer (score 0):

**Here we have Two method available for TextFormField widget**

> 1. Use textCapitalization sample code below (consider it is a common widget so, certain conditions there)

```
  textCapitalization: widget.isCapitalize == true
        ? TextCapitalization.characters
        : TextCapitalization.none,
```

> 2. This method achieve with controller and onChanged(value) event (consider it is a common widget so, certain conditions there)

```
onChanged: (value) {
      if (widget.controller.text != value.toUpperCase() &&
          widget.isCapitalize == true) {
        widget.controller.value =
            widget.controller.value.copyWith(text: value.toUpperCase());
      }
    },
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a util class that can help with it:

```
 class TextCapitalizationFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
      final TextCapitalization capitalization;

  TextCapitalizationFormatter(this.capitalization);

  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    String text = '';

    switch (capitalization) {
      case TextCapitalization.words:
        text = capitalizeFirstofEach(newValue.text);
        break;
      case TextCapitalization.sentences:
        List<String> sentences = newValue.text.split('.');
        for (int i = 0; i < sentences.length; i++) {
          sentences[i] = inCaps(sentences[i]);
          print(sentences[i]);
        }
        text = sentences.join('.');
        break;
      case TextCapitalization.characters:
        text = allInCaps(newValue.text);
        break;
      case TextCapitalization.none:
        text = newValue.text;
        break;
    }

    return TextEditingValue(
      text: text,
      selection: newValue.selection,
    );
  }

  /// 'Hello world'
  static String inCaps(String text) {
    if (text.isEmpty) {
      return text;
    }
    String result = '';
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
      if (text[i] != ' ') {
        result += '${text[i].toUpperCase()}${text.substring(i + 1)}';
        break;
      } else {
        result += text[i];
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

  /// 'HELLO WORLD'
  static String allInCaps(String text) => text.toUpperCase();

  /// 'Hello World'
  static String capitalizeFirstofEach(String text) => text
      .replaceAll(RegExp(' +'), ' ')
      .split(" ")
      .map((str) => inCaps(str))
      .join(" ");
}
```

Usage:

```
TextField(
  inputFormatters: [
    TextCapitalizationFormatter(TextCapitalization.sentences),
  ]
)
```

Answer (score -2):

This works on every platform:

```
TextEditingController mytext = TextEditingController();
```

```
TextField(
  controller: mytext,
  onChanged: (value) {
    mytext.value = TextEditingValue(
      text: value.toUpperCase(), 
      selection: mytext.selection,
    );
  },
)
```