# Flutter TextFormField isnt showing the Value typed in it

Tags: flutter, dart

So my `TextFormField` is just showing 1 character when it is typed but when the character was deleted and retyped it didn't show anything, but the value was shown on the keyboard recommendations.

Heres my `TextFormField` code:

```dart
Form(
  key: _code,
  child: TextFormField(
    controller: codeController,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      fillColor: Colors.transparent,
      filled: true,
      labelText: 'Kode Akses',
      labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
      ),
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        borderSide:BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 30.sp),
      ),
      focusColor: Colors.red,
    ),
    inputFormatters: [UpperCaseTextFormatter()],
  ),
),
```

[image: Error happened]

Here I typed `YOU` but it doesn't show anything in the `TextFormField`.

As I discovered, the value isn't got inside the `TextFormField` so,for anything I type, the value isn't fill in the `TextFormField`.

Comment: can you share what about your _code and codeController, I comment out this two and then working fine

Comment: @JahidulIslam I just figure it out, the controller has no relation in it, it happened because of this code `inputFormatters: [UpperCaseTextFormatter()]`, in the iOS emulator it work just fine, but when it used on Real Android phone it just dont insert the value

Comment: Your code working correctly . if any problem go to my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68645258/13997210

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil it does work fine on my iOS emulator but not on my Android phone, btw Thank You for trying to help, also i tried your solutions but it doesnt seem to work on my iOS emulator but it does work on my android phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `inputFormatters: [UpperCaseTextFormatter()]` code, and change it to `textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters`,