# Flutter Make Textfield input become uppercase

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield, uppercase

Update(2023/12/05):

I fixed it with setting `keyboardType` to `TextInputType.visiblePassword`

Is any update for this question [Flutter TextField value always uppercase & debounce](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49238908/19539222) ?

I've already tried some of the code to make the input text become uppercase.

```
class UpperCaseTextFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    return TextEditingValue(
      text: newValue.text.toUpperCase(),
      selection: newValue.selection,
    );
  }
}
```

```
class UpperCaseTextFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    return newValue.copyWith(text: newValue.text.toUpperCase());
  }
}
```

But it works not correct when I type "QWER", it will always become "QQWQWEQWER"

```
TextFormField(
  controller: _controller,
  inputFormatters: [
    UpperCaseTextFormatter(),
  ],
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
  ),
),
```

Here is the video : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q3dwuVMPzt_kBP4c2lyiahQ6znkSbM-n/view?usp=sharing

I prefer not to use `textCapitalization` because the user still can change it to lowercase, if the formatter doesn't work.

Use TextInputFormatter to make textfield input become uppercase

Comment: TextField(
    textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
)

Comment: Could you provide your `Textfield` code? I couldn't reproduce the issue in both android emulator and iOS simulator with Flutter 3.16.0.

Comment: I updated my TextFormField.And I use flutter 3.10.5

Answer (score 0):

You can use **TextEditingController** to make user input always UPPERCASE, With the below code the user can't change it to lowercase.

```
TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

TextFormField(
  controller: _controller,
  onChanged: (String text) {
    _controller.text = text.toUpperCase();
  },
);
```

This will work Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

1. Assign a controller to the TextField.
2. Convert the text value in controller with `toUpperCase()` in the `onChanged` function:

   ```
   TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

   TextFormField(
     controller: _controller,
     onChanged: (String text) {
       _controller.text = text.toUpperCase();
     },
   );
   ```